# Shadow-catcher stays noisy even with Denoising - also very dark

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, shadows, noise-reduction, denoise

I am facing some issues with the shadow-catcher and denoiser in Blender 2.79.
Denoising doesn't seem to have any effect on shadow catcher shadow. If I turn off shadow catcher on ground plane the desnoising works well. But if it's turned on - the shadow stays noisy.

Also the shadow become much darker with shadow catcher turned on.

Am I doing something wrong?
How do I get noise free contact shadow and lighter shadow like the left render?

[image: Shadow-catcher is noisy even with denoiser also very dark]
Here is the .blend file of the scene in case someone wants to inspect it:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48592

[image]

Will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please don't use pasteall.org to host files. Links on that site expire after some time and users that might face a similar issue will not be able to learn from your file once it is not available anymore. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share files used for questions and answers.

Comment: Denoiser is not a substitute for higher number of samples. 128 samples is not a lot.

Comment: Thank you cegaton. Updated the .blend file link. 
I know 128 sample isn't enough but - the question is not about how to remove noise - it's about how to get denoising work on shadow catcher shadows. Also I the shadow catcher shadow doesn't match the no-shadow catcher ground plane - it's much darker.
These seem to be some important issues that anyone can face...

Comment: You can't composite a shadow using a nonlinear application. Further, the proper operation should be a multiply against your background.

Comment: Thanks Troy. Yes I thought non-linear application could be a reason for the dark shadow as I am using PNG format. It's in multiply mode against a white background. I am not sure how to control the intensity of the shadow as the shadow is in the same layer as the object. 

Also I follow similar shadow catcher workflow with 8Bit/16Bit PNG format in other software (Modo) but it doesn't look so dark compared to solid background.

Answer (score 3):

It's because denoising works only with RGB-channels, not alpha-channel.
You can try to denoise it in compose nodes.

I use **Bilateral Blur** to denoise alpha channel in render, then set it in result picture by Set **Alpha node**. Extract ground plane by object ID mask:

[image]

Comment: In Blender 2.90, passing the alpha channel through a denoise node cleans the shadow up.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your background will look like later on you can change the sky to that colour. Then the shadow will be denoised. However, this won't have alpha then.
I use that trick very often because I mostly just need a white background but for your application it may vary.