# Render shadows without denoise on a transparent background in cycles

Tags: transparency, shadows, denoise, noise-reduction, shadowcatcher

I have a problem with the graininess that appears in the shade. I want to render an object with a nice and clean shadow. The result is a *png with a transparent background.*

Render in **Cycles** engine. I have enabled **Shadow Catcher, Transition, RGBA, Denoising - OpenImageDenoise** . The number of Samples is **1000**.

Can I fix this problem somehow?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shadow-catcher stays noisy even with Denoising - also very dark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97265/shadow-catcher-stays-noisy-even-with-denoising-also-very-dark)

Comment: One way to solve this problem is to render the shadow catcher in a separate view layer. Then, in the compositor, add a blur node for this view layer, then alpha over the other layer. C.f. linked question.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but I solve this issue by passing the "Alpha" from "Render Layers" through a HDR Denoiser, then use the denoised alpha map to blend with the background image to generate the noise free shadow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but it still doesn't work. I created nodes in compositor: https://ibb.co/xq72WgV  , but result is still same

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue in a very similar scenario, I bumped up the samples to 2500 and used NLM denoise.
I tried many other tricks and variations but to this date, couldn't find a better solution other than just using more samples.